# Accessing values in list in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list in the form like this

[(x1,y0,output), (x1,y1,output), (x1,y2,output),
(x2,y0,output), (x2,y1,output), (x2,y2,output)]

[(1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 0, 0), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 4)]

I would like to get cells in the list with a specific condition.

For example,

1. I want all of the cells which x = 1

   I hope the result is: [(1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2)]
2. I want all of the cells which x = 1, y = 2

   I hope the result is: [(1, 2, 2)]

How can I do this?

```
import numpy as np

result = []
for x in np.arange(1, 3, 1):
    for y in np.arange(0, 3, 1):
        res = y * x
        res = (x, y, res)

        result.append(res)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a list comprehension:

```
listy = [(1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 0, 0), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 4)]
list1 = [e for e in listy if e[0]==1]
list2 = [e for e in listy if e[0]==1 and e[1]==2]
```

You can change the conditions you choose by in that last `if` part of the list comprehension.

Comment: How can I get the third value in the cell? For example, the result I get from [e for e in result if e[0] == 1 and e[1] == 2] is [(1, 2, 2)]. How can I get the result only shows the third value -> [2]

Answer (score 2):

You could use list comprehension for this. For example, with your given inputs.

```
>>>[x for x in result if x[0] == 1]
[(1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2)]
>>>[x for x in result if x[0] == 1 and x[1] == 2]
[(1, 2, 2)]
```

Comment: How can I get the third value in the cell? For example, the result I get from [x for x in result if x[0] == 1 and x[1] == 2] is [(1, 2, 2)]. How can I get the result only shows the third value -> [2]

Comment: @Joanne You could index the x value that's being returned from the iteration. `[x[2] for x in result if x[0] == 1 and x[1] == 2]` returns `[2]`.